# Upgrade from Angular 2 to 4 Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular

So I just upgraded from 2.4.8 to 4.1.1, and I'm getting a call stack size exceeded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had a component with an entrycomponent of itself - I had a component that would run recursively. I just had to remove it from the entrycomponent, and now I'm gucci.